# What does ^ and $ do in nginx.conf location?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, openresty

```
location ~ ^/test/(?<id>\d+)$ {
    postgres_pass    database;
    rds_json         on;
    postgres_escape  $name $id;
    postgres_query   "SELECT $name";
}
```

The code snippet above was taken from https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres/issues/4.

Can someone explain to me what ^ does and what $ does?
I can't find documentation that explain it.
Checked https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a regular expression. Google regular expressions.

`^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. In other words, this regex matches only if the part between `^` and `$` matches all of the value of `location`. So only URLs beginning with `/test/`, followed by one or more digits and the end of the string, will match.

Comment: In the code snippet above, it is not necessary to include the ^ and $ correct? Because in the official documentation they never used ^ and $ at all https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres#sample-configuration-5

Comment: @Geoyws that depends. Do you want to match a URL like `/foo/bar/test/123abcdefg`? Probably not. If not, then yes, you need those characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Ed.